# How to set height of WebView according to the length of content in Nativescript-Vue?

Tags: vue.js, webview, markdown, nativescript

> Update: I used HtmlView and yes, the height is dynamic with the content,
>   but it seems like not support `<img />`

I'm currently using WebView to render the markdown content as below

```
<WebView :src="marked_content" height="1200px" margin="20dp" />
```

The result is fixed at 1200px with scrollBar as expected, but what I actually want to do is to render the whole markdown content with various height and without scrollBar.

Anyone may help, please?

PS: Any other methods which may render markdown content is welcome! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have control over the website, if Yes you can do this

https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/dynamic-webview-height/4215/2?u=manojdcoder

Comment: Thank you @Manoj! This is a good approach! But sadly not all the time we do own the website ;(

Comment: That's the easiest way, there are other options to do that without modifying the site but that requires bit native coding at least with Android as Java annotations can't be marshalled into JavaScript yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked out how to do this without plugins.
There is a solution above which appends the URL with a hash containing the page height. It didn't work for me because I'm adding HTML code directly. 
For example

```
src="<p>blah blah</p>"
```

This is a plain JS solution, so you'll have to rework it to get it working in Vue / Typescript.
Give your WebView an id, do not set the height, and add the "loaded" and "loadFinished" handlers.
For the loaded handler.

```
platformModule = require("tns-core-modules/platform");
var webViewSrcObj = {};
exports.webViewLoaded = function(webargs){
    if(platformModule.isAndroid){console.log("IS ANDROID!!!"); return false;}
    webview = webargs.object;
    if(webview.height == "auto"){
        webViewSrcObj[webview.id] = webview.src;
        webview.src += '<script>function getPageHeight(){if(document.documentElement.clientHeight>document.body.clientHeight){height = document.documentElement.clientHeight}else{height = document.body.clientHeight}; ph = document.getElementById("pageHeight"); window.location = "pageHeight.html?height="+height;} setTimeout(getPageHeight, 1);</script>';
    }
}
```

It checks the platform, and returns false if it is Android (Android works fine already).
Then it checks if the height is set to "auto" (which is default).
if it is set to auto, it will copy the HTML content. I'll explain more about this later. It then appends the html with some JavaScript code that calculates the view height, and then redirects to an empty page. It does this in order to use the query string for the page height. Make sure that page exists in your app folder to avoid any page not found errors!

Then for the onLoadeFinished handler...

```
exports.webViewLoadFinished = function(webargs){
    if(platformModule.isAndroid){
        console.log("IS ANDROID!!!"); return false;
    }
    webview = webargs.object;
    if(webargs.url.indexOf("?height") > -1){
        height = (webargs.url).split("?height=");
        height = height[1].substr(0, height[1].length)/1;
        webview.height = height; webview.src = webViewSrcObj[webview.id];
    }
}
```

This will check to see if the query string height value exists.
If so it uses the height value to set the height of the webview.
And finally it adds the HTML content that was copied in the onLoaded handler.
My initial testing works well even with multiple webviews in a page.
I haven’t done extensive testing, but it might help to increase the setTimeout time if you experience any problems.
If anyone is able to improve this solution, please share your results.